# Замена текста в документах Word с помощью Python

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

Не являюсь программистом, но немного изучал Python. Возникла необходимость написать небольшую программу для личных нужд. ТЗ: Есть шаблон документа в docx, в нужных местах стоят теги {{tags}}. Программа на входе получает переменную и, исходя из нее, получает другие переменные и подставляет всё по тегам в документе. Работу с одной переменной я осилил благодаря этому сайту(все работает и меняет), но вопрос как сделать, чтобы он менял остальные переменные. Var2 var3 итп. Реально ли это сделать используя данную библиотеку или лучше воспользоваться другими библиотеками? И еще один вопрос - можно ли, исходя из введенной пользователем переменной, выбрать название файла для редактирования?

p.s привожу кусок кода без генерации вторичных переменных, на данный момент волнует именно их замена  в документе

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate    #импортировал библиотеку

var1 = input()                      #запросили у пользователя переменную
doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx') #открываем шаблон
context = { 'Var' : var }           #меняем переменную в шаблоне {{Var}} на введенную 
doc.render(context)         
doc.save("ready.docx")              #сохраняем файл
```

Comment: лучше сразу присваивать переменные в программе, если у вас нет массового формирования документов, напрvиер, с данными из базы данных. ведь можно ошибиться при вводе данных с консоли. а тут у вас будут проверенные данные.  var1 = "мои данные" ## input()/  потом можете организовать переменные в электронной таблице, как вариант. подготовили таблицу, с именами файлов и переменными и оптом сформировали нужные документы из шаблона.

Comment: это, вероятно, уже читали https://habr.com/ru/company/skillfactory/blog/553224/

Comment: Переменные я присвою, они будут формироваться исходя из введенной.   Как их в самом документе заменить массово? В самом тексте шаблона их несколько. а context меняет мне только одну. Массовой обработки документа не будет. В конкретный момент идет работа, только с одним шаблоном.

Comment: @nexoma за ссылочку спасибо, видимо не правильно вбивал запрос в гугле, на хабр меня не заводило, пошел изучать)

Comment: а, вы этого не поняли, тут должно быть просто. попробуйте context = { 'Var' : var , 'var22' : 'вторые данные', 'var3':'третьи данные'}

Comment: Все, теперь понял, попробовал - сработало! Получается банальный словарь. Спасибо большое

Comment: а теперь плавно переходим на формат .odf  - odt, ods  ;-)

Comment: да хоть rtf =) главное, я понял принцип, а библиотеку текстового редактора поменять - не проблема.